# How to give access to specific person to use aws -elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, kibana, ip-address, amazon-iam

I have created aws - elasticsearch instance in aws. It has a link of kibana. I want to give access to specific person.Such that only that person can access that link .What can I do?

I can allow IP specific access but that is very generic and IP keeps changing every time.

Comment: [Authentication in Kibana | Kibana User Guide  6.7 | Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.7/kibana-authentication.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein What about access of aws-elasticsearch ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a [walkthrough on the AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/get-started-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-use-amazon-cognito-for-kibana-access-control/) to use Cognito for access control to Kibana on AWS ElasticSearch, complete with IAM policy samples and AWS console screenshots showing you where to click.

The summary is this:

1. Create a user pool in Amazon Cognito
2. In the ElasticSearch console, select the checkbox for "Enable Amazon Cognito for authentication" and tell it to use your user pool.
3. Create a Cognito user and a group which you will use to access Kibana
4. Update the policy on your ES cluster to allow members of the Cognito User pool to assume an Auth role for the ES cluster.